# How to take the mean of last 10 values in a column before a missing value using R?

Tags: r, moving-average

I am new to R and having trouble figuring out to go about this.  I have data on tree growth rates from dead trees, organized by year.  So, my first column is year and the columns to the right are growth rates for individual trees, ending in the year each tree died.  After the tree died, the values are "NA" for the remaining years in the dataset.  I need to take the mean growth for the 10 years preceding each tree's death, but each tree died in a different year.  Does anyone have an idea for how to do this? Here is an example of what a dataset might look like:

```
Year    Tree1   Tree2   Tree3
1989    53.00   84.58   102.52
1990    63.68   133.16  146.07
1991    90.37   103.10  233.58
1992    149.24  127.61  245.69
1993    96.20   54.78   417.96
1994    230.64  60.92   125.31
1995    150.81  60.98   100.43
1996    124.25  42.73   75.43
1997    173.42  67.20   50.34
1998    119.60  73.40   32.43
1999    179.97  61.24   NA
2000    114.88  67.43   NA
2001    82.23   55.23   NA
2002    49.40   NA  NA
2003    93.46   NA  NA
2004    104.67  NA  NA
2005    44.14   NA  NA
2006    88.40   NA  NA
```

So, the averages I need to calculate are:

```
Tree1: mean(1997-2006) = 105.01
Tree2: mean(1992-2001) = 67.15
Tree3: mean(1989-1998) = 152.98
```

Since I need to do this for a large number of trees, it would be helpful to have a method of automating the calculation.  Thank you very much for any help!  Katie

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet...I'm so new to R that I have no idea where to start with this.  Looking through a few related questions, I'm wondering whether rollmean or tapply might be a starting point?

Comment: There will definitely be no `NA` values in the years the tree was alive?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `sapply` and `tail` together with `na.omit` as follows:

```
sapply(mydf[-1], function(x) mean(tail(na.omit(x), 10)))
#   Tree1   Tree2   Tree3 
# 105.017  67.152 152.976
```

`mydf[-1]` says to drop the first column. `tail` has an argument, `n`, that lets you specify how many values you want from the *end* (tail) of your data. Here, we've set it to "10" since you want the last 10 values. Then, assuming that there are no `NA` values in your actual data from while the trees are alive, you can safely use `na.omit` on your data.

Comment: Thank you so much. This did exactly what I was hoping and will save me a great deal of time in automating these calculations. I really appreciate your help with this as I doubt I would have figured it out on my own.  And, yes, there are no NA values in my actual data from while the trees are alive...they have been checked for that.  Thank you! Katie

Comment: That should be `mydf[,-1]`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft mydf[-1] == mydf[,-1]

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I think your comment applies if `mydf` were a `matrix`, but here, I'm assuming since it's called "my*df*", that it is a `data.frame`.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen, for a `data.frame`, yes, but for a `matrix`, no. Carl's suggestion is a good one for consistency (but I'm not always consistent).